# Every object isomorphic to a coproduct of terminal objects

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $C$ be a category with coproducts and terminal object $1$ such that every object in $C$ is isomorphic to a coproduct of $1$ with itself (indexed over some set). Is there a special name for such a category?

EDIT: Interested specifically in the case in which $C$ is a topos.

Comment: A subcategory of **Sets**?

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't it rather be something like a "quotient" of **Sets** instead, via $J\mapsto\bigvee_J 1$ on objects, and with some natural definition on functions (which I don't want to write here)?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: There is a canonical functor from $\mathbf{Sets}$ to any such category which is essentially surjective on objects, but it need not be a full functor.  For instance, the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Sets}^2$ consisting of objects of the form $(X,X)$ is one such category, but the image of your "quotient" functor contains only the morphisms that are the same on both coordinates.

Comment: @egreg is right: The functor from $C$ to the category of sets which maps an object $X$ to the set $\mathrm{Hom}_C(1,X)$ of global elements of $X$ is fully faithful. (@egreg, are you Greg Egan, my favourite science fiction author?)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Sorry, no. 

Answer (score 1):

These are precisely the [cocartesian](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocartesian+monoidal+category) categories $\mathbf{C}$ for which the (singleton set containing the) terminal object $\{ 1 \}$ is a *colimit-dense generator*. See, for instance, §III.7 of Adámek–Tholen's [Total Categories with generators](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82678851.pdf). I do not believe there is a more specific name; examples seem sparse.